# Close java processing thread

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

In a GUI application, when I have to make massive data manipulation (accesses to the DB), I create a thread that opens a loading dialog, closing this dialog when the processing ends.
However, I want this processing to be interrupted if the Loading dialog is closed. Today, it opens the next view even if the loading dialog was closed.

How can I do this? while(run){} is not applicable because it runs only once and then the thread exits. Also interrupt does not work because I don't have any blocking method.

Comment: Interrupt it in the event.. when closing the dialog

Comment: I was already doing this, but it was missing the verification in the thread as assylias commented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also interrupt does not work because I don't have any blocking method.

I suppose you do something like:

```
while(resultSet.hasNext()) {
    //do something
}
```

You can change that to:

```
while(resultSet.hasNext()) {
    if (Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) break;
    //do something
}
```

Your task will now exit when you interrupt the running thread.

Comment: +1 So when the Loading dialog is closed, it should interrupt the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use `myThread.interrupt()` in your Dialog closing event which will cause all waiting stuffs (sleep, wait, blocking ios) to stop. If possible, add also some checks in your code with `if (Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted())`.